# cannot ping using my interfaces MTU

Tags: networking, ping, mtu

I'm trying to find the best MTU for my network to try and improve my PS4 as it's a bit poor.

On my PC, when I run the command:
netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces

It tells me my MTU is 1500.

But when I run the command (bbc as an example):
ping bbc.co.uk -f -l 1472

I always get a time out and won't start working until I change the MTU down to 1460.

I can however, simply run 'ping bbc.co.uk', which works every time and presumably is using 1472 given 1500 is the current setting.

Is there any reason for this? Also, and I'm not entirely sure why, but if I change the website to google the ping is very sporadic and I have to knock it down even lower to get a result, which I've no idea why.

thanks.

Comment: Where are you altering your MTU? on your pc? on your router? on your modem? on your ps4?

Comment: ping never uses the full MTU by default; it usually uses only 32~64 bytes of payload.

Comment: There's a simple online tester you can try at http://www.letmecheck.it/mtu-test.php

Answer (score 0):

Your PC may have a MTU of 1500, but your router or ISP may not. It would seem you are exceeding the **M**aximum **T**ransmission **U**nit somewhere upstream, thus pings over a certain size are being dropped (since you are explicitly saying 'don't fragment' with -f).

Standard windows ping packets are 32 bytes. Non-standard ping packets may be seen as possible DoS attacks.

Sounds like your MTU 1460. And if anything, modifying your Windows MTU to reflect this may increase its network performance, as your router won't need to fragment packets generated by your PC.